# Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/app/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, serve

Using Serve to serve my React app. It seems that too many people are reading the static files. but somehow it is not getting closed. Due to this the react app is crashing

```
events.js:177
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/app/build/index.html'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:151:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:155:23) {
  errno: -24,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/app/build/index.html'
}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Abhishek - No. we only faced this issue once. Still looking for fix